# Exit a multiprocessing script

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-3.5

I am trying to exit a multiprocessing script when an error is thrown by the target function, but instead of quitting, the parent process just hangs.

This is the test script I use to replicate the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import time, multiprocessing as mp

def myWait(wait, resultQueue):
    startedAt = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    time.sleep(wait)
    endedAt = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
    name = mp.current_process().name
    resultQueue.put((name, wait, startedAt, endedAt))

# queue initialisation
resultQueue = mp.Queue()

# process creation arg: (process number, sleep time, queue)
proc =  [
    mp.Process(target=myWait, name = ' _One_', args=(2, resultQueue,)),
    mp.Process(target=myWait, name = ' _Two_', args=(2, resultQueue,))
    ]

# starting processes
for p in proc:
    p.start()

for p in proc:
    p.join()

# print results
results = {}
for p in proc:
    name, wait, startedAt, endedAt = resultQueue.get()
    print('Process %s started at %s wait %s ended at %s' % (name, startedAt, wait, endedAt))
```

This works perfectly, I can see the parent script spawning two child processes in `htop` but when I want to force the parent script to exit if an error is thrown in the `myWait` target function the parent process just hangs and doesn't even spawn any child process. I have to `ctrl-c` to kill it.

```
def myWait(wait, resultQueue):
    try:
        # do something wrong
    except:
        raise SystemExit
```

I have tried every way to exit the function (e.g. `exit()`, `sys.exit()`, `os._exit()`...) to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your code has a major issue: you're trying to join the processes before flushing the content of the queues, if any, which can result in a deadlock. See the section titled 'Joining processes that use queues' here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing-programming

Secondly, the call to `resultQueue.get()` will block until it receives some data, which never happens
if an exception is raised from the `myWait` function and that no data has been pushed into the queue before then. So make it non-blocking and make it check for any data in a loop until it finally receives something or that something's wrong.

Here's a quick'n'dirty fix to give you the idea:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5

import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import time

def myWait(wait, resultQueue):
    raise Exception("error!")

# queue initialisation
resultQueue = mp.Queue()

# process creation arg: (process number, sleep time, queue)
proc =  [
    mp.Process(target=myWait, name = ' _One_', args=(2, resultQueue,)),
    mp.Process(target=myWait, name = ' _Two_', args=(2, resultQueue,))
    ]

# starting processes
for p in proc:
    p.start()

# print results
results = {}
for p in proc:
    while True:
        if not p.is_alive():
            break

        try:
            name, wait, startedAt, endedAt = resultQueue.get(block=False)
            print('Process %s started at %s wait %s ended at %s'
                  % (name, startedAt, wait, endedAt))
            break
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

for p in proc:
    p.join()
```

The function `myWait` will throw an exception but both processes will still join and the program will exit nicely.

Comment: `get(block=False)` did the trick. Your _quick'n'dirty fix_ trow other errors from the multiprocessing lib though, but it's definitely getting there. Thanks.

Comment: Truth to be told, I've been running this code snippet using Python 3.4 but there doesn't seem to be any impactful change in 3.5 that would change its behaviour. On my side I don't get any error except the one voluntarily thrown with the `raise Exception("error!")` line. What's the error log like in your case?

Comment: `File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 249, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
` and `File "/usr/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
`

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my previous comment, that's to be expected... you only copy/pasted the 2 first entries from the traceback but it then continues onto the line `raise Exception("error!")`, which is the real source of the error. I only put this exception here to demonstrate that even if your code goes wrong, as you've been mentioning in your question, then your processes now join as they should and the program exits nicely. So just remove this exception and replace it with the actual content of the `myWait` function.

Comment: I have edited my answer to mention the expected behaviour.

Comment: This answer uses a busy loop, which is less than ideal.

Comment: It's probably not the only “less than ideal” thing in there but hopefully it still does its job of answering the specific question. That being said I wouldn't know how to do it otherwise so I'd love to see your approach if you've got some time to spare!

Comment: @ChristopherC I've submitted an answer if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `multiprocessing.Pool` to manage your processes for you. And then use `Pool.imap_unordered` to iterate over the results in the order they are completed. As soon as you get the first exception, you can stop the pool and its child processes (this is automatically done when you exit the `with Pool() as pool` block). eg

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def my_wait(args):
    name, wait = args
    if wait == 2:
        raise ValueError("error!")
    else:
        startedAt = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        time.sleep(wait)
        endedAt = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.localtime())
        return name, wait, startedAt, endedAt

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        with Pool() as pool:
            args = [["_One_", 2], ["_Two_", 3]]
            for name, wait, startedAt, endedAt in pool.imap_unordered(my_wait, args):     
                print('Task %s started at %s wait %s ended at %s' % (name,
                    startedAt, wait, endedAt))
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)
```

This method is not suitable for long-timed, low-workload tasks, as it will only run as many of the tasks in parallel as the number of child processes it is managing (but this is something you can set). It's also not great if you need to run different functions.

Comment: Ah, I didn't expect seeing `Pool` here since it's a solution to a different set of problems. Thanks for taking the time nonetheless!

Comment: Looks promising and terse, compared to my attempt. As for the real thing (this was just a test bench), I am looking to send simultaneously only 2 http requests and get their results. So, only one target function of short-timed processes. Your method seems to be perfectly suitable. Thanks.